# Accessing data from netcdf files and displaying it in browser

Tags: javascript, netcdf

The issue is that I'm only getting the first value as the output even though my netcdf file contains a lot of values.

```
import { NetCDFReader } from "netcdfjs";

fetch(
  "http://localhost:8000/test/example_files/synthetic_square/dzdata_files/0/0_0.nc",
  { method: "GET" },
)
  .then((response) => response.body.getReader().read())
  .then((data) => {
    let netcdfReader = new NetCDFReader(data.value);
    let heights = netcdfReader.getDataVariable("heights");
    let allHeights = new Float64Array(heights);

    console.log(heights);
    console.log(allHeights);
  });
```

This is the output:

```
Array [ 0.2859144424892198 ]
0: 0.2859144424892198
length: 1
<prototype>: Array []
```

How can I get all of the values? What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the file as a `Blob`, since the `NetCDFReader` constructor takes an `ArrayBuffer`.

```js
import { NetCDFReader } from "netcdfjs";

fetch(
  "http://localhost:8000/test/example_files/synthetic_square/dzdata_files/0/0_0.nc",
  { method: "GET" }
)
  .then((response) => response.blob())
  .then((blob) => blob.arrayBuffer())
  .then((arrayBuffer) => {
    let netcdfReader = new NetCDFReader(arrayBuffer);
    let heights = netcdfReader.getDataVariable("heights");
    let allHeights = new Float64Array(heights);
    console.log(heights);
    console.log(allHeights);
  });
```

I tested this with the following file:

> https://github.com/RaymanNg/3D-Wind-Field/blob/master/data/demo.nc

Other test files can be found at the netcdfjs repo:

> https://github.com/cheminfo/netcdfjs/tree/main/src/__tests__/files

```js
import { NetCDFReader } from "netcdfjs";

// Source: https://github.com/RaymanNg/3D-Wind-Field/blob/master/data/demo.nc
fetch("https://github.com/RaymanNg/3D-Wind-Field/raw/master/data/demo.nc", {
  method: "GET",
})
  .then((response) => response.blob())
  .then((blob) => blob.arrayBuffer())
  .then((arrayBuffer) => {
    let netcdfReader = new NetCDFReader(arrayBuffer);
    console.log(netcdfReader.version); // classic format
    console.log(netcdfReader.dimensions); // lev, time, lat, lon
    let lat = new Float64Array(netcdfReader.getDataVariable("lat")); // Size: 361
    console.log(lat);
  });
```

Here is a modern `async`/`await` version:

```js
import { NetCDFReader } from "netcdfjs";

// Source: https://github.com/RaymanNg/3D-Wind-Field/blob/master/data/demo.nc
const path = "https://github.com/RaymanNg/3D-Wind-Field/raw/master/data/demo.nc";

const response = await fetch(path, { method: "GET" });
const blob = await response.blob();
const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
const netcdfReader = new NetCDFReader(arrayBuffer);

// CDF info
console.log(netcdfReader.version); // classic format
console.log(netcdfReader.dimensions); // lev, time, lat, lon

// Lattitude
const lat = new Float64Array(netcdfReader.getDataVariable("lat")); // Size: 361
console.log(lat);
```

Here is another example:

```js
import { NetCDFReader } from "netcdfjs";

// Source: https://github.com/cheminfo/netcdfjs/blob/main/src/__tests__/files/agilent_hplc.cdf
const path = "https://github.com/cheminfo/netcdfjs/raw/main/src/__tests__/files/agilent_hplc.cdf";

const response = await fetch(path, { method: "GET" });
const blob = await response.blob();
const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
const netcdfReader = new NetCDFReader(arrayBuffer);

// CDF info
console.log(netcdfReader.version); // classic format
console.log(netcdfReader.header.variables.map(({ name }) => name)); // Data variables

// Peak Area
if (netcdfReader.dataVariableExists("peak_area")) {
  const peak = new Float64Array(netcdfReader.getDataVariable("peak_area")); // Size: 8
  console.log(peak);
}
```